# cURL in CMD | Using response variable to another POST call

Tags: batch-file, curl, cmd

I need to call POST using cURL from **Windows CMD**, After that I need to use some variable to call another POST call.

The response of the first POST is:

```
{"status":200,"description":"Operation successful","response_time":"2022-10-18T14:38:03.9185574Z","data":{"Id":41654964}}
```

I need to use the `"id"` number to run this according POST:
[https://api.commbox.io/managers/15454545/assignments?objectId=`["id"]`](https://api.commbox.io/managers/15454545/assignments?objectId=%60%5B%22id%22%5D%60)

How it can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: No.  It cannot be done.  You need to write an app to do that.

Comment: Really? No option?
What is the easier way to write an app for it?

Comment: You need someway to  put the data from the first response into the second request.  It would be a simple app.  Do you know any programming  language?

Comment: It's been 5 days since you posted and no one has helped you.  I need to know what you know in order to help you.    Are you familiar with using `for /f` or `token` in CMD?  I'm not.  But I think your solution is in understanding those CMD commands.  Your answer may be found here:  https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html  
Let me know if you want my help.

Comment: @Misunderstood My knowledge is quite poor but I'm quick-learning.
I will appreciate your further help. Any way to contact you privately?

Comment: Rubbish. There are tools like [tag:xidel] that can do this no problem. No need to "write an app". If you would disclose the first POST-request, then there's a pretty good chance you can combine both in one go.